# Do the neural networks belonging to a deep ensemble need to be trained on the same training set?

Tags: neural-networks, uncertainty, ensemble-learning

As the title says, I was wondering, if I have to train every neural network of a deep ensemble on a different training set or on the same one. I ask this question because I am getting weird results.  If I use the same training set I get overconfident  predictions and the deep ensemble fails to estimate the epistemic uncertainty. I think this happens because each network end up finding the same solution instead different solutions spread over the parameter space (? or it's the feature space? not sure).

[image]

If instead I change the training set for every element I get worthless predictions

[image]

Update: after further inspection, it seems that some of the networks of the ensemble do not learn and the average predicted value remain close to 0 for all input. This shift the mean of the ensemble toward 0.

How can I improve the quality of the estimate of the uncertainty?

Comment: How did you assign the training set for each network?

Comment: @kmkurn  i tried  both approaches: passing new X_train,y_train  lists generated with  sklearn train_test_split to each network of the ensemble and with passing the same x_train, y_train to every network. in the second case i get overconfident results, in the first  case i get the ugly plot posted above